# Why is NPM audit giving errors and NPM install will not fix it

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to setup my ionic application.
When I run npm install, it creates a package-lock.json but the node_modules folder is not created.
I run the npm install command again and I get no errors but on nom audit I see several missing packages.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "5.0",
  "author": "uuuu",
  "homepage": "https://www.eee.eee.com/bbbb/home/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
  "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
"@angular/core": "5.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
"@angular/http": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/http": "^4.7.0",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.5.3",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.4.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"cordova": "^8.1.2",
"cordova-background-geolocation-lt": "^2.9.1",
"cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
"cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.11.1",
"cordova-plugin-background-fetch": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack": "0.0.4",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
"cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
"g": "^2.0.1",
"ionic": "^4.4.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"leaflet": "^1.2.0",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^7.0.2",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"ts-md5": "^1.2.2",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.5",
"typescript": "2.4.2"
},
"description": "The sample description.",
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file": {},
  "gov.usda.iphis.mobile.eauth": {},
  "gov.usda.iphis.mobile.http": {},
  "cordova-background-geolocation-lt": {
    "BACKGROUND_MODE_LOCATION": "",
    "LOCATION_ALWAYS_AND_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Always use    is required for background location tracking",
    "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Background location-tracking is required",
    "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Background location-tracking is required",
    "MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Using the accelerometer increases battery-efficiency by intelligently toggling location-tracking only when the device is detected to be moving"
  },
  "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
    "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Camera usage is required"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {
    "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Camera usage is required"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
  "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
    "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack": {},
  "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "ios"
]
```

}
}

```
AAPMDRD2PAASINGs-MacBook-Pro:iphis-mobile superuser$ npm install
npm WARN Invalid version: "5.0"
npm WARN iphis-mobile No description
npm WARN iphis-mobile No repository field.
npm WARN iphis-mobile No README data
npm WARN iphis-mobile No license field.

audited 22426 packages in 2.682s
found 0 vulnerabilities

AAPMDRD2PAASINGs-MacBook-Pro:iphis-mobile superuser$ npm audit
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/common@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/compiler@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/core@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/forms@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/http@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/platform-browser@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/barcode-scanner@^4.5.3
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/camera@^4.5.3
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/core@4.4.0
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/file@^4.5.2
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/http@^4.7.0
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/in-app-browser@^4.5.3
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/keyboard@^4.5.2
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/native-geocoder@^4.5.3
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/network@^4.4.2
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.4.0
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic-native/status-bar@4.4.0
npm ERR!     Missing: @ionic/storage@2.1.3
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova@^8.1.2
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-background-geolocation-lt@^2.9.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-ios@4.5.4
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-add-swift-support@^1.7.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-advanced-http@^1.11.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-background-fetch@^5.1.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-camera@^4.0.2
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack@0.0.4
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-device@^1.1.4
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-file@^6.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@^2.0.2
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@^1.1.16
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder@^3.1.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-network-information@^1.3.4
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-splashscreen@^4.0.3
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-statusbar@^2.4.1
npm ERR!     Missing: cordova-plugin-whitelist@^1.3.1
npm ERR!     Missing: g@^2.0.1
npm ERR!     Missing: gov.usda.iphis.mobile.background-download@file:gov.usda.iphis.mobile.background-download
npm ERR!     Missing: gov.usda.iphis.mobile.eauth@file:gov.usda.iphis.mobile.eauth
npm ERR!     Missing: gov.usda.iphis.mobile.exit@file:gov.usda.iphis.mobile.exit
npm ERR!     Missing: gov.usda.iphis.mobile.http@file:gov.usda.iphis.mobile.http
npm ERR!     Missing: ionic@^4.4.0
npm ERR!     Missing: ionic-angular@3.9.2
npm ERR!     Missing: ionic-plugin-keyboard@^2.2.1
npm ERR!     Missing: ionicons@3.0.0
npm ERR!     Missing: leaflet@^1.2.0
npm ERR!     Missing: phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@^7.0.2
npm ERR!     Missing: rxjs@5.5.2
npm ERR!     Missing: sw-toolbox@3.6.0
npm ERR!     Missing: ts-md5@^1.2.2
npm ERR!     Missing: zone.js@0.8.18
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/cli@^1.5.0
npm ERR!     Missing: @types/leaflet@^1.2.5
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's typescript@2.6.2 does not satisfy typescript@2.4.2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/superuser/.npm/_logs/2019-06-13T15_57_54_937Z-debug.log
AAPMDRD2PAASINGs-MacBook-Pro:iphis-mobile superuser$
```

I expect that all packages are installed and npm audit does not show any errors.

Comment: Does it show a package.json file in your project?